# AngularJS ui-grid DateTime column

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I would like to have a column in my angularjs ui-grid that displays a datetime eg"dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss".
I have found heaps of documentation on using date fields, but there seems to be nothing for datetime fields. When I use the following columnDefs, the TimeDown field renders blank.
Has anyone had any success with datetime columns?
Thanks in advance.
Damien.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection:true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'IncidentRef',displayName:'Incident', width:'20%' },
        { name: 'Areas' },
        { name: 'TimeDown', type:'datetime',cellFilter: 'datetime:"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm"'},
        { name: 'TotalNumberOff', displayName: 'Total off', width: '10%' }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Check this link for date.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 2):

Thanks S. Divya, that reference helped. The problem was the type 'datetime'. It should be 'date'. Here is the working code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableRowSelection:true,
columnDefs: [
    { name: 'IncidentRef',displayName:'Incident', width:'20%' },
    { name: 'Areas' },
    { name: 'TimeDown', type:'date',cellFilter: 'date:"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm"'},
    { name: 'TotalNumberOff', displayName: 'Total off', width: '10%' }
]};
```